# Unable to configure SR-TE (Segment Routing Traffic Engineering) in CSR 1000v

Tags: cisco, routing, router, networking, ios-xe

I'm trying to configure SR-TE (Segment Routing Traffic Engineering) in CSR 1000v IOS XE 16 using the official tutorial in here [Segment Routing Traffic Engineering (SR-TE)](http://www.segment-routing.net/tutorials/2017-03-06-segment-routing-traffic-engineering-srte/)

I have the same topology in AWS where 6 CSR 1000v routers are deployed there. When I started the configuration the command `segment-routing` then I got `% Incomplete command`.
After I checked the possible commands, I got this:

```
csr1000v(config)#segment-routing ?
mpls Segment Routing MPLS Mode
```

Where in the tutorial is showing something else, how can I have the same configuration as it is shown in the tutorial?

Comment: What software version are you using contra the version used in the tutorial? Do you have the same licenses?

Comment: @Cown `Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.08.01` deployed in AWS

Comment: Does it say what version the tutorial is using? I'm unable to download the PDF as i'm not member.

Comment: @Cown actually you can download the tutorial even you are not a member. However, it does not show which version is used in there.

Comment: Ok, well that might be the problem. That the tutorial uses another version or the license might be different enabling more features in the tutorial.

Comment: @Cown well, the license should not be a problem since it is deployed on AWS. I would agree with the version. Is there any possible solution to implement SR-TE on IOS-XE version?

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but according to Cisco support, the official deployment guide for version 16.8 "Fuji" is located here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/seg_routing/configuration/xe-16-8/segrt-xe-16-8-book.html

Comment: @Cown well, that's unfortunate! it does not meet my needs. Have you tried SR on IOS-XR based version?

Comment: Unfortunately, downloading the tutorial does require logging into the site. It appears to be a case of differences between IOS versions, and we cannot help with that. I think you are going to need to adapt the tutorial and use the `segment-routing mpls` command required by your IOS version. I do not see how we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, `Segment Routing Traffic Engineering`  which is introduced in here[Segment Routing Traffic Engineering (SR-TE)](http://www.segment-routing.net/tutorials/2017-03-06-segment-routing-traffic-engineering-srte/) is available only in `IOS XR`.